# How can I type-check an abstract class and a derived instance are passed to a generic function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to type-check a `register` function to receive 2 parameters:

- A class, abstract or not;
- An instance of the class, or any derived instance that passes isinstance(...) check.

Example:

```python
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def register(klass: Type[T], instance: T):
    print("Registering class", klass, "with instance", instance)

class MyAbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> None:
        pass

class MyClass(MyAbstractClass):
    def foo(self) -> None:
        print("Executing foo")

register(MyClass, MyClass())  # Type-checks successfully
register(MyAbstractClass, MyClass())  # Doesn't type-checks

print(isinstance(MyClass(), MyAbstractClass)) # Still, this is True
```

The example above works for regular classes, but doesn't when I pass an abstract class to `register`. Mypy says "*Only concrete class can be given where "Type[MyAbstractClass]" is expected  [type-abstract]*"

Is there a way to accept abstract classes and still enforce the `instance` type to be derived from it?

Bonus: if you know how to do this for Protocols too it's gold.

Comment: Bigger problem: `register(MyClass, object())` type-checks. `T` is inferred as `object`, and `MyClass` is a `Type[object]`. I don't remember if there's a way around the problem.

Comment: True... although I wouldn't mind this. I may also do a runtime check, but at least I'd like to have the abstract case accepted to have better IDE completion.